# iOS PushPlugin Cordova issue in registration

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working **Cordova iOS** Platform. I need to add **Push Notification** in my Project.

**Steps:**

1. I have created a project in Google console and created a Project-ID.
2. Created a APNS PushNotification Production Certificate from Apple Developer.
3. Below Plugin Added in my Project

   `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="722784892462"`

**In index.js**

```
   var pushNotification; 
gcmNotification = {
  onNotificationAPN : function (e) {
      if (e.id)
      {
        navigator.notification.beep();
        
      }
  },
  registerPushNotification : function () {
     try{
      pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;     

      var errorHandler = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      };

      var tokenHandler = function (result) {
          alert('device token = ' + result);
      };

      pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "onNotificationAPN" });

    }catch(e){
      exceptionAlert("registerPushNotification>>"+e);
    }
  }
}

function onNotificationAPN(e)
{
  gcmNotification.onNotificationAPN(e);
}
```

*I tried in my **real** device.*

I got the Below error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've found the solution.
I have replaced the code from **PushNotification.js** to **Push.js**

> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/master/www

and added the below code in **index.js**

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679"
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u add cordova.js file in your html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: cordova.js is already added. My other Plugins are working great except this

Comment: i tried this one is working for me. check this url https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin